# How to count eloquent relationship without the N+1 issue and loading the entire model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

I am showing a list of categories, and the article count within each category. I get the expected result, but I am having the N+1 problem.

My `CategoriesController` index function:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('categories.index', [
        'articleCategories' => Category::where('type', 'articles')->orderBy('name')->get(),
    ]);
}
```

The `Category` model has many relationship to articles:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Article');
}
```

My `categories.index` view:

```
@foreach($articleCategories as $articleCategory)
    <p>
    {{ HTML::link(URL::route('articles.category', array('category' => Str::slug($articleCategory->name))), $articleCategory->name) }}
    {{ $articleCategory->articles->count() }}
    </p>
@endforeach
```

**Edit:** It works if I eager load all related articles, but since I only need the article count pr category this seems overkill. Will eager loading articles and do `->count()` impact performance? Or is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you do: `count($articleCategory->articles);`? I think that's most easy and most fast.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get it working with that method, but ideally I would like to not load the all related articles. I have updated my question.

Comment: Loading multiple Eloquent models is overkill. If you have 100 rows, then you don't need to worry about it, but for thousands+ I wouldn't go that way definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// helper relation
public function articlesCount()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Article')->selectRaw('category_id, count(*) as aggregate')->groupBy('category_id');
}

// and accessor for fetching it easier
public function getArticlesCountAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('articlesCount', $this->relations)) $this->load('articlesCount');

    return $this->getRelation('articlesCount')->aggregate;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
// eager load in single query
$categories = Category::with('articlesCount')->get();

// thanks to accessor this will return value and load relation only if needed
$categories->first()->articlesCount;
```

Comment: Thanks again Jarek, haven't had time to try this out yet. Will accept when I do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('categories.index', [
        'category' => Category::with('articles')->where('type', 'articles')->orderBy('name')->get(),
    ]);
}
```

Now in View to get the category data just do

`$category->type` or if you have a name field you can get the name by`$category->name`

To get the articles of the category you can do

```
foreach($category->articles as $article)
// do something with the articles
@endforeach
```

To get the count of articles of a category do `$category->articles->count();`

Make sure you also read documentation of [Eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) once, it really helps a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with this method. But since I only need the count it seems overkill to load all the related articles. Will this impact performance?

Comment: I get your point, I don't think there will be much of a performance issue, but the other way I can think of is by left joining the articles on category model then counting the number of articles in countArticles method. The traditional method, I believe.