# laravel 4 - join latest result in group by query

Tags: mysql, join, laravel-4, max

This query gives a pagination of all 'albums' with a picture and description for each. Now I am trying to get always the latest picture of each album.

I have tried to add a second `orderBy('pics.created_at')` , but that did not work. I think I need some kind of subquery but don't know how.

```
        $query = AlbumPic::select(DB::raw('COUNT(pics.id) as picscount, 
                                           pics.url, 
                                           pics.user_id, 
                                           pics.created_at,
                                           albums.id as album_id, 
                                           albums.title, 
                                           albums.text, 
                                           users.username'))
                        ->join('albums','albums.id','=','album_pic.album_id')
                        ->join('pics','pics.id','=','album_pic.pic_id')
                        ->join('users','users.id','=','pics.user_id');

                if(!is_null($user_id)) 
                  $query->where('album_pic.user_id',$user_id);

        $albums = $query->groupBy('albums.id')
                        ->orderBy('albums.created_at','desc')
                        ->paginate(20);
```

### edit

I made a mistake. I don't have created_at and updated_at in the album_pic table .
So my 'Album' - model/relations are now like this:

```
public function pics()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Pic');
}

public function latestPic()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Pic')->latest('pics.created_at');
}
```

And the query now looks like this:

```
        $q = Album::with('pics')->with('latestPic.users');

                if(!is_null($user_id)) 
                  $q->where('albums.user_id',$user_id);

        $albums = $q->orderBy('albums.created_at','desc')
                    ->paginate(20);
```

This works. Only thing I would like to improve is the way, the pictures per album are counted. Now I get all with `with('pics')` and then do a `count($album->pics)` in the view. If there is a way to *not* load everything, but only count the pictures, it would be nice.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: also, laravel says: "Note: Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database manually and use Paginator::make."

Comment: ok. now, I always get the first picture from the album_pic table. I want to get the picture with the _latest created_at - value_ in pics - table. So that I don't have always the same picture, but always the latest picture of the album.

Comment: Can a picture belong to multiple albums?

Comment: yes, a picture can be in multiple albums. album_pic is a pivot table that only stores the relation of pics and albums. (id,pic_id,album_id,created_at,updated_at)

Comment: There is a fairly convoluted method of getting a `count` without loading all the pics, but I'm not sure if it's worth the trouble from a performance standpoint, and if you're not careful it can lead to a bunch of additional queries. The method is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26004948/4043861) and [here](http://laravel.io/forum/05-03-2014-eloquent-get-count-relation).

Comment: I do believe that in your edited `latestPic` code above, you should be calling `->latest('album_pic.created_at')` (and you should have a `created_at` column in your pivot table) rather than `->latest('pics.created_at')`. If pics can belong to multiple albums, then right now you are getting the pic in an album that was most recently added to the *database*, rather than the pic that was most recently added to that *album*. So if someone adds a photo to an album that has already been used in another album, that photo might not show up as the `latest` photo in that album.

Comment: If you do have `created_at` in your `album_pic` table, make sure you define the `belongsToMany` relationship to include `->withTimestamps();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `MAX(created_at)` inside a subquery; see [MySQL select MAX(datetime) not returning max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049997/mysql-select-maxdatetime-not-returning-max-value) for example.

Really, though, if you're doing this in Laravel, it would be better to set these all up as relations and leverage the power of Eloquent. Then, you can define a relationship for pictures that uses `->latest()` to return the most recent. See [laravel eloquent query group by last id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549345/laravel-eloquent-query-group-by-last-id/26555444#26555444) for an example (which uses one table, but the principle is the same for multiple tables).

---

Here's how you could set this up using Eloquent relations:

**User model (User.php)**

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function albums()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Album');
    }
}
```

**Album model (Album.php)**

```
class Album extends Eloquent {

    public function pics()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Pic');
    }

    public function latestPic()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Pic')->latest('album_pic.created_at');
    }
}
```

Because you have a many-to-many relationship between albums and pics, in the `latestPic()` relation, you must specify the `album_pic.created_at` field for `latest()`—since we are actually interested in the order of entries in the pivot table, rather than in the `pics` table.

Finally, link this all together. For example, for a user with `id` of `1`:

```
$albums = User::find(1)->albums()->with('pics')->with('latestPic')->paginate(20);
    foreach($albums as $album) {

        echo('<br>Album:');
        var_dump($album->title);

        echo('All pics:');
        foreach($album->pics as $pic) {
            var_dump($pic->url);
        }

        echo('Latest pic:');
        $latestPic = $album->latestPic->first();

        if ($latestPic) {
            var_dump($latestPic->url);
        }
}
```

Note that we are eager loading the `pics` and `latestPic` to reduce the number on calls to the database. Also note that accessing the `$latestPic->url` is wrapped in an `if` statement, otherwise albums that do not have any photos will throw an error since `$album->latestPic` would return `null`.

As @cedie correctly noted, Laravel doesn't handle pagination all that efficiently when using a `groupBy` statement, but that shouldn't be a problem in this case. The underlying queries do not use `groupBy`, so you should be save to use `->paginate(20)`.

Comment: sounds good. I tried with this relationship, but it gives me all pics instead of the latest. does `latest()` work with `belongsToMany` ?            ````public function pics()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Pic')->latest();
    }````

Comment: Yes, with some caveats. First, you need to specify the field in `latest` as `album_pic.created_at`, since you are interested in the order of pics in the *pivot table*, not their order in the `pics` table. (Otherwise, you would get the most recent pic added overall, not the most recent pic added to a particular album.) Then, when you access the `latestPic` relation, you want to `->first()`, not `->get()`. (BTW, all `latest()` does is add an `orderBy('created_at')` clause to your query.) I've edited the answer with tested code that should work for you...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your select query:

```
max(pics.created_at) as created_at
```

instead of this:

```
pics.created_at
```

So your code should look like this:

```
AlbumPic::select(DB::raw('COUNT(pics.id) as picscount, 
                                           pics.url, 
                                           pics.user_id, 
                                           max(pics.created_at) as created_at,
                                           albums.id as album_id, 
                                           albums.title, 
                                           albums.text, 
                                           users.username'))
```

Comment: did not work. only 2 of all images were loaded. did not yet figure out why exactly

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ypu can figure out how to adapt this for your purposes...

```
SELECT ap.*
     , p.* 
  FROM album_pic ap 
  JOIN pics p
    ON p.id = ap.pic_id
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT ap.*
            , MAX(p.created_at) max_created_at 
         FROM album_pics ap 
         JOIN p.*
           ON p.id = ap.pic_id
     ) x
    ON x.album_id = ap.album_id
   AND x.max_created_at = p.created_at;
```